# How to Autoplay within in an a tag?

Tags: html

Is there a way to autoplay a video in `<a>` tag.

I have an image as a button and when i click the image a video is displayed but i would like it to autoplay.

```
  <a id="myVideo"  href="IKEA creative ad.mp4"  ><img class="img-thumbnail" src="play-button-icon.png"/></a>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you display your video with HTML5 <video> tags or do you access the video directly through the url?

Comment: I am using HTML 5 to load my video. My video pops-up and plays above my webpage.

Comment: Ok, bukke's answer should work for you then. use autoplay attribute in video tag.

Comment: IT will work if the video is on the webpage not in the pop up widow

Comment: Is your video self hosted or is hosted inside another platform?

Comment: Its a local video file on my computer. I the code from here http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Lightweight-jQuery-Plugin-To-Render-Modal-Videos-ModalVideo.html

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for the support Diego -->" Is your video self hosted or is hosted inside another platform" In my javascript there was a video tag and i just added "autoplay". Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Use video tag. Do not use a tag.

```
<video controls autoplay>
 <source src="IKEA_creative_ad.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The autoplay attribute in the video tag will auto play the video when the page is loaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video - refer this for more information.

Use this code

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').onclick = function() {
  var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
  vid.play(); 
}
```

Comment: My video pops-up and plays above my webpage. src="play-button-icon.png is what the user will click on.

Comment: Is the pop up a custom pop-up? Like a bootstrap modal? If so then put the video tag inside the popup.

Answer (score 0):

If your video is inside a popup, you can bind a click event to your link and autoplay from over there.

```
document.getElementById("myVideo").addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.querySelector('.modal-body video').autoplay = true;
});
```